# How can I manually remove TFS Build Services?

Tags: tfsbuild

I've got a major mess that I'm hoping someone can help me fix. I have a Windows 2008 server and a Windows 2003 Server which I've installed TFS Build Services on. Originally I configured the Windows 2008 machine (VM) to run a Build Controller with one Build Agent. This seemed to set up fine however I decided to reconfigure it and removed the Build Agent.
When I reinstalled on the Build Services on Windows 2003, It says 1 Build Controller and 0 Build Agents running on 3 machine(s).

Unfortunately, I had issues where I wasn't able to get the BuildAgent accounts to log in so now I have unregistered build services from both 2003 and the 2008 vm. I've uninstalled TFS Build Services from both VMs and rebooted. Now when I attempt to reinstall and reconfigure TFS Build Services on the Windows 2003 VM I get an error saying that a buildservicehost is already on the machine and that it will be deleted, however in the next step the wizard gives an error when it attempts to delete the BuildServiceHost. Is there a way to remove TFS BuildService and any artifacts?

Answer (score 1):

If you look through your running services can you see the original build service? could you then use "sc delete" from command prompt to get rid of it? also, have you tried changing to the next free port up on install?

there's a bunch ([link](http://sorin.serbans.net/blog/index.php/2010/07/27/configure-build-in-tfs2010-and-multiple-build-agents-on-the-same-build-machine/)) of posts on tinternet about getting multiple build services running on one host, what you're trying to do is undo that situation?